# How to print the nearest alphanumeric to a character input in a C program?

Tags: c, printf, character, ascii, alphanumeric

*Here's the exact question:*

**Write a C program that takes a character as input and prints the alphanumeric character (0-9, A-Z, a-z are alphanumeric characters) that is closest to this character. NOTE: If the input character is equidistant from two alpha-numeric values, either one can be printed.**

I know we would have to use the ASCII table and make some cases but I can't figure out how to exactly do it.

Comment: Post your code! What did you try?

Comment: If the input does not exist in the range of A-Za-z0-9 then you should write a series of if statements to figure out which range it is closest to and from which side.

Comment: Note that character input can be outside the ASCII 0-127 range.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the solution relies on ASCII values. You can simply use an **if-else-if ladder** to figure out the closest alphanumeric character to the input character. If the input is already an alphanumeric character, you can use the built-in `isalpha` and `isdigit` functions to quickly arrive at the solution. If it is not then make use of either of the **comparison operators** `<` or `>`, and figure out in which end of these ranges **0-9**, **A-Z**, **a-z** your solution lies in.

The order in which you make the comparisons is important in order to reduce the number of comparisons. Here is the [ASCII Table](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html) for reference.

Since you are new to this site, take my code and learn from it. But you may not always get your solution in the form of complete code over here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char input, tmp, result;

    printf("Enter the input character: ");
    scanf("%c", &input);

    if (isalpha(input))
    {
        tmp = input - 1;
        result = isalpha(tmp) ? tmp : input + 1;
    }
    else if (isdigit(input))
    {
        tmp = input - 1;
        result = isdigit(tmp) ? tmp : input + 1;
    }
    else if (input < '0')
    {
        result = '0';
    }
    else if (input > '9' && input < 'A')
    {
        result = (input - '9' > 'A' - input) ? 'A' : '9';
    }
    else if (input > 'Z' && input < 'a')
    {
        result = (input - 'Z' > 'a' - input) ? 'a' : 'Z';
    }
    else
    {
        result = 'z';
    }

    printf("Alphanumeric character closest to '%c' is '%c'", input, result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Subtle, preferred and correct use of `unsigned char input` vs. `char input` here.